# "Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Tags: powershell

I am trying to setup to download need files to automate and install process. I keep getting errors ever time I run the script and I have changed it seven ways from sunday and it still gives me errors.

The script is:

```
  if (test-path $java_path)

   {
   Write-Output "Java already installed. Skipping script"
   exit 0
    }

  else 

    {
      $source = "http://our.server.com/java-installer.zip"
      $destination = "c:\CHPACS"
      $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
      $client.DownloadFile($source, $destination)

      }
```

The error message that I am getting is

```
 Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
 At C:\ps_script\testjava.ps1:41 char:31
 +           $client.DownloadFile <<<< ($source, $destination)
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Do I need to create a function to make this work properly?

Thank you:

Comment: After hitting the error, can you execute `$error[0].Exception.ToString()` and post the results?  That should give more detail.

Comment: From the error message it looks as though the variables are not being passed to the $client.DownloadFile($source, $destination). I tried what you requested but did not gain any addtional information.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you look at the MSDN documentation for the `DownloadFile` method, you'll notice that the second parameter is a *filename*, not a directory.  So, if you re-define `$destination` to something like:

```
$destination = "c:\CHPACS\java-installer.zip"
```

then it should work.

Check secondly that the file that you're trying to download isn't open or being executed at the moment. This exception will be raised if the file is in use.

Comment: OIC like with any download the source and destination don't have to have the same name. The file can be renamed at the destination. It works now.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the full path to the destination file is required. I was initially having problems getting this to work with a relative one.

Comment: It also seems to happen if you can't write to the destination file. Mine was locked by another process and couldn't overwrite.

Comment: Stumbled on this answer when searching for the same error but I still get the error when the destination is the full path with file name.

Comment: Also turns up if the path to the destination does not exist.  So, in the example above, if the path "c:\CHPACS" does not already exist, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 21):

You should give a file name as David said + the folder should exist.

Comment: thanks for "the folder should exist" - exactly my case!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the URL wasn't reachable on the machine I was trying to execute the script. Had to enable proxy rules to scope it to the machine to download the file.

Comment: This is the common one