# Using Powershell to download files from Google Drive

Tags: powershell, download, google-drive-api

I'm trying to find a solution to downloading files from Google Drive (shared files, *not files I own*) to a location on a server / network drive.

I was using:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Credentials =  Get-Credential
$client.DownloadFile("https://docs.google.com/a/domainname.co.uk/spreadsheets/d/1in0m8PhfiYhu4qCWO1dxNc3OS3p8prF7HWRZ-bjnKBI/export?format=xlsx","W:\Corp\Comp Serv\Comp Op\OB\Dep Data\Call\Google backup")
```

However it returns with the message:
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

So I added the following line between Credentials and DownloadFile:

```
$client.Proxy.Credentials =[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

This has solved the (407) Proxy Authentication Required problem, but now I'm getting the error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception
> occurred during a WebClient request."

> At line:1 char:21

> - $client.DownloadFile <<<< ("https://docs.google.com/a/domainname.co.uk/spreadsheets/d/1in0m8PhfiYhu4qCWO1dxNc3OS3p8prF7HWRZ-bjnKBI/export?format=xlsx","W:\Corp\Comp Serv\Comp Op\OB\Dep Data\Call\Google backup")
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

And, because I'm pretty much a complete beginner with Powershell, I have no idea why I'm getting this message.

Eventually, I need it to download a total of 4/5 files, all to the same location... also, ideally, I need this to run via a batch command or something equivalent so it can be a (almost) 1 Click solution...

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in DownloadFile should be a file path, not a path to a directory.

See here:
[Error using $client.DownloadFile in Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712462/error-using-client-downloadfile-in-powershell-script)

EDIT: To solve the proxy exception you need to set the proxy authentication for your call.
Example:

```
$source = "https://docs.google.com/a/domainname.co.uk/spreadsheets/d/1in0m8PhfiYhu4qCWO1dxNc3OS3p8prF7HWRZ-bjnKBI/export?format=xlsx"
$dest = "W:\Corp\Comp Serv\Comp Op\OB\Dep Data\Call\Google backup\download.xlsx"
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy("http://myproxy.com:1111",$true)
$Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential("user,"","domain.local")
$Credentials = $Credentials.GetCredential("http://myproxy.com","1111", "KERBEROS");
$WebProxy.Credentials = $Credentials
$WebClient.Proxy = $WebProxy
$WebClient.DownloadFile($source,$dest)
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1a05b90b-ce12-4974-b578-0c1e22d03f10/download-file-through-proxy-server

Comment: Totally missed that, cheers!. So something like: `W:\Corp\Comp Serv\Comp Op\OB\Dep Data\Call\Google backup\Document.xlsx` should work instead?

Comment: Awesome, cheers Dustin. While you're here, I don't suppose you could point me in the direction of converting it to a batch script? Cheeky, I know...

Comment: Ah, nuts. Now its returning with the (407) Proxy Auth message again :/

Comment: sorry, don't know the best way to call your PS script from a batch file.

Comment: No worries, one step at a time! Looks like the modifications to the script above aren't doing anything...

Comment: Although, I have a feeling this may be because the corperate network is blocking out proxies...