# Download file from Google Drive with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, download, flysystem-google-drive

In trying to download a file with PowerShell I have the following

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile($AGRIDATAMISCURL,$TESTAGRIDATAMISCZIP)
```

Where `$AGRIDATAMISCURL` is a URL that looks like "https://drive.google.com/file/d/<...>" and `$TESTAGRIDATAMISCZIP` looks like "C:\test\A.zip"

This script doesn't return an error but the file it downloads is basically an HTML file with a prompt to sign in to Google. Is there another way to download a file that is "shared with me"?

Comment: Have a look at the answer offered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985446/using-powershell-to-download-files-from-google-drive

Comment: You may also want to search for answers with the word `OAuth` and/or in combination with PowerShell or Google Drive.

Comment: The link provide although helpful mainly resolves a proxy error and a misunderstanding of file path versus folder path. Since this does not involve a proxy and a complete file path has been provided this link doesn't give any additional information. Searching for PowerShell and OAuth does provide options. But how to convert those options to Google Drive (particulary "Shared With Me" files) remains elusive.

Answer (score 4):

### Share the file first

Files in Google Drive must be made available for sharing before they can be downloaded. There's no security context when running from PowerShell, so the file download fails. (To check this, rename the file with a `.html` extension, and view in a text editor).

Note: the following solution assumes that the links are to non-security-critical files, or that the links will only be given to those with whom access can be trusted (links are https, so are encrypted with transmission). The alternative is to programatically authenticate with Google - something *not* addressed in this answer.

To Share the file, in Google Drive:

1. Right-click the file, and choose **Get shareable link**

   [image: Get Shareable Link]

---

2. Turn link sharing on

[image: Link Sharing On]

---

3. Click **Sharing Settings**

[image: Sharing Settings]

---

4. Ensure that **Anyone with the link can view** (Note that in corporate environments, the link must be shared with those outside the organization in order to bypass having to login)

[image: Share with others]

---

### Then Download Programatically

5. Then, code can be used to download the file as such (in this case with Windows PowerShell):

---

```
# Download the file
$zipFile = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1cwwPzYjIzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $zipFile -OutFile "$($env:TEMP)\myFile.doc"
```

---

- Replace the `1cwwPzYjIzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz` with the ID code from the shareable link setting back in step #2, above.

Comment: it just downloads HTML page instead of the file

Comment: Working in 2023

Comment: This actually works in late April 2023, but Google Drive share links format has changed since @CJBS answer. I made a new answer in this post to clearly how you can achieve the download with the new links.

Answer (score 1):

A ***confirm*** parameter is now needed in order to download the file without confirmation. I'm using the following approach with WebClient:

```
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_ID_HERE&confirm=t"
$WebClient.DownloadFile($Url, "C:\Download\file_name.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here to add on @CJBS's answer. The following solution works for **FILES ONLY** :

Note that in 2023, Google drive share links format has changed since CJBS answer. They do not contain **explicity** an id anymore but rather a string of numbers and letters after an `/d/` that most-likely represents the id of the shared file.

Take this share link for example :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SE04CUOPdUKGcloOYDpifOlamy70mcpx/view?usp=sharing
```

I took the link in @CJBS's answer :

`"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=<INSERT_STRING_AFTER_/d/>`

and just after the `id=` I added the `1SE04CUOPdUKGcloOYDpifOlamy70mcpx` that's between `/d/` and `/view` in my share link and my download link for Powershell became like this :

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1SE04CUOPdUKGcloOYDpifOlamy70mcpx
```

My Powershell command with the download link included is the following :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1SE04CUOPdUKGcloOYDpifOlamy70mcpx" -OutFile ./Dex.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated instructions for 2024. They changed the URL and you need a uuid value.

```
# set protocol to tls version 1.2
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Download the Virus Warning into _tmp.txt
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$FileID" -OutFile "C:\temp\_tmp.txt" -SessionVariable googleDriveSession

$htmlContent = Get-Content "C:\Temp\_tmp.txt"

# Regex pattern to match the uuid value
$pattern = '<input type="hidden" name="uuid" value="(.+?)">'

# Perform regex match to find the uuid value
if ($htmlContent -match $pattern) {
    $uuidValue = $matches[1] # Captured group 1 contains the uuid value
    Write-Output "UUID Value: $uuidValue"
} else {
    Write-Output "UUID value not found."
}

# Delete _tmp.txt
Remove-Item "C:\temp\_tmp.txt"

# Download the real file

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=$FileID&export=download&confirm=t&uuid=$uuidValue" -OutFile C:\Temp\file.zip -WebSession $googleDriveSession
```